Managing services with fixed ports in NUnit tests to prevent port conflicts
I'm working on NUnit tests where each test case requires starting a service that uses a fixed port. The challenge I'm facing is ensuring that the service setup ([SetUp] method) runs only once per test fixture class and that ports used by the service are available and not already in use by another test case. Here are the details:

Environment: Visual Studio (version 16.11.11)
.NET Framework: 4.8
NUnit Version: 2.6.3

Problem Description:

Each test case requires starting a service that listens on a fixed port.
If multiple test cases run concurrently or in rapid succession, there is a risk of port conflicts because the service setup may attempt to reuse a port that is already in use by another test case.
I need a strategy to ensure that:

The service setup ([SetUp] method) runs only once per test fixture class.
Ports used by the service are managed to prevent conflicts between test cases.



What I've Tried:

Using static flags and lock statements to manage setup execution.
2, Ensuring that each test case handles cleanup ([TearDown]) properly.

Expected Outcome:
I expect a solution or best practices to manage service setup in NUnit tests where ports are fixed, ensuring that tests run reliably without port conflicts.
Additional Notes:

I'm open to suggestions on how to handle port management effectively in a NUnit 2.6.3 environment with .NET Framework 4.8.
Detailed code examples or configuration recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Can anyone provide insights or solutions on managing services with fixed ports in NUnit tests to prevent port conflicts?
Effective Port Management: I expect a solution or best practices to efficiently manage service setup in NUnit tests, ensuring that ports used by services are handled to prevent conflicts between test cases.
Concurrency Safety: Insights on handling concurrent test executions to ensure setup actions (such as starting services) are synchronized and do not cause port conflicts.

Please explain how you are using terms Test, TestCase, TestFixture, which seems to be different from how NUnit itself uses the terms. NUnit defs: Test method = a method carrying the Test or TestCase or a few other attributes; TestCase = a test method plus its data if parameterized; TestFixture a class containing test methods; Test = any of the proceeding plus a namespace or an assembly containing tests. You have said you want one port used per test case but also one port per TestFixture, which is my main point of confusion.
